# Definition of a totally odd character

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K/F$ be a finite Galois extension of number fields and let $G:=\textrm{Gal}(K/F)$. If $\chi: G \rightarrow \mathbb C^{\times}$ is a character, what does it mean for $\chi$ to be totally odd?

I could not find a precise definition elsewhere and hence I am asking it here.

Comment: I assume $G=Gal(K/F)$. If $K$ has a complex embedding $\sigma$ and $\sigma(F)\subset \Bbb{R}$ with $\rho$ the complex conjugaison  then $\sigma^{-1}\rho\sigma\in G$ and you can ask that  $\chi(\sigma^{-1}\rho\sigma)=-1$ for all such $\sigma$.

Comment: Yes, I have corrected it. So in other words, every complex conjugation of $K$ must be mapped to -1?